# useEffect show a warning if I call a function in throw props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm using hooks in React, and I see this warning in my console. I searched using Google Search, but I did not find the best solution. Why does this warning come and how can I resolve to this?

> Line 9:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. However, 'props' will change when *any* prop changes, so the preferred fix is to destructure the 'props' object outside of the useEffect call and refer to those specific props inside useEffect  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
> printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:120
> handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:125
> push../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:190
> push../node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/eventtarget.js.EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:56
> (anonymous) @ main.js:283
> push../node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/main.js.SockJS._transportMessage @ main.js:281
> push../node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js.EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:53
> WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ websocket.js:36

My code is this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.firtstTimeCourseList();
    console.log("____UserEffect call function here ");
}, []);
```

Comment: what do you mean by throw props?

Comment: we used this function in props.firstTimeCourseList();

Comment: None of the answers solved your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass all dependencies when declaring the second argument off `useEffect`.

The problem is `firtstTimeCourseList` is a `callback` provided via `props`, which means it doesn't have an stable signature therefore changes every render, always triggering the effect. You can wrap your callback with an additional layer of dependency check with `useCallback`

```
const Component = ({ handlerFromParent }) => {
    // Assuming that the handler doesn't have to change
    const stableHandler = useCallback(handlerFromParent, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        stableHandler()
   }, [stableHandler])
}
```

For more details, check [this article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) from Dan Abramov.

Comment: useCallback should be used in the Parent that creates handlerFromParent to avoid stale closure problem (see my answer).

Answer (score 5):

You should use useCallback in the component where you create handlerFromParent. Consider the following example:

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const add = () => setCount(count => count + 1);
  const aCallback = () => count;
  return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <button onClick={add}>+</button>
      <Child aCallback={aCallback} />
    </div>
  );
}
function Child({ aCallback }) {
  const cb = useCallback(aCallback, []);
  return <div>{cb()}</div>;
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

And here is the example where useEffect is used in the parent:

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const add = () => setCount(count => count + 1);
  const aCallback = useCallback(() => count, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <button onClick={add}>+</button>
      <Child aCallback={aCallback} />
    </div>
  );
}
function Child({ aCallback }) {
  return <div>{aCallback()}</div>;
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Nice answer! Showing an use case where the callback need to change.

Answer (score 3):

If useEffect has any dependencies, those need to be added in square brackets.

```
const { firtstTimeCourseList } = props;
useEffect(() => {
    firtstTimeCourseList();
    console.log("____UserEffect call function here ");
  }, [firtstTimeCourseList]);
```

Comment: You have to define the firtstTimeCourseList const outside the useEffect.

Comment: This could cause the effect to run too many times, to solve that you can use useCallback but that could cause stale closure when not done in the parent (see my answer).